# JPanel flickering issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

For my game, I paint to a `java.awt.Image` then draw the Image onto a JPanel. I do this for a couple of reasons, mainly because I didn't want game rendering to hog up cpu cycles on the EDT, and for portability.

A problem arised which caused flickering on the `java.awt.JPanel` when using

> graphics#drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height,
>   ImageObserver observer)

.

However,

> graphics#drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)

did not cause this issue.

Here is my code:

Sandbox.java

```
public class Sandbox implements Paintable {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GameWindow window = new GameWindow("Test", 800, 600);
    GameScreen screen = new GameScreen(800, 600);
    Sandbox sandbox = new Sandbox();

    window.add(screen);
    window.setVisible(true);

    boolean running = true;
    while(running) {
        sandbox.update();
        screen.getPaintBuffer().clear();
        screen.getPaintBuffer().paint(sandbox);
        screen.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
    }

}

private int x = 0, y = 0;

public void update() {
    x++;
    y++;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

}
```

GameWindow.java

```
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

public GameWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(width, height);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}

}
```

GameScreen.java

```
public class GameScreen extends JPanel {

private ImageBuffer buffer;

public GameScreen(int width, int height) {
    buffer = new ImageBuffer(width, height);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(getPaintBuffer().getBuffer(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}

public ImageBuffer getPaintBuffer() {
    return buffer;
}

}
```

Paintable.java

```
public interface Paintable {

public void paint(Graphics g);

}
```

ImageBuffer.java

```
public class ImageBuffer {

private final Image buffer;
private int width, height;

public ImageBuffer(int width, int height) {
    buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void paint(Paintable paintable) {
    paintable.paint(buffer.getGraphics());
}

public void clear() {
    buffer.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

public Image getBuffer() {
    return buffer;
}

}
```

Comment: I'd say its a fluke that one worked and the other didn't

Comment: Flukes happen once, they're not easily reproducible, this bug is.

Comment: Mate, if you're confident of that, then file a bug report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `GameScreen`'s `paint` method to...

1. Override `paintComponent` instead
2. Call `super.paintComponent` in order to maintain the paint chain's contract
3. Pass `this` as the `ImageObsever` parameter to `drawImage`

For example...

```
public class GameScreen extends JPanel {

    private ImageBuffer buffer;

    public GameScreen(int width, int height) {
        buffer = new ImageBuffer(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(getPaintBuffer().getBuffer(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }

    public ImageBuffer getPaintBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

}
```

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

**Updated**

The basic problem is a scaling issue...

The image you're using to draw with is `800x600`, but the `GameScreen` is actually `794x572` (on my PC), this causes the image to be scaled.  Now, Swing's default scaling isn't pretty and is based on speed over quality generally.

Now, there are a number of ways you could improve this, but a quick way would be to apply some higher rendering hints, for example

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    g2d.drawImage(getPaintBuffer().getBuffer(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Now, I've gone overboard with this, so you might want to remove some and see what changes

**Updated**

Rendering hints could slow the rendering process down, so a better solution might to override the `getPreferredSize` method of `GameScreen` and return the expected size

```
public static class GameScreen extends JPanel {

    private ImageBuffer buffer;
    private Dimension size;

    public GameScreen(int width, int height) {
        buffer = new ImageBuffer(width, height);
        this.size = new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }
```

Then, rather then passing the size to `GameWindow`, simply call `pack`

```
GameWindow window = new GameWindow("Test");
GameScreen screen = new GameScreen(800, 600);
Sandbox sandbox = new Sandbox();

window.add(screen);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

This way, everybody's on the same size

Comment: I've tried using paintComponent instead, it doesn't change anything. I don't want to use an ImageObserver and that isn't relevant anyways. Also I don't call super.paint(g) because I don't intend to add any components to this class. 

Either way, these changes are not relevant, and do nothing to fix my issue.

Comment: @ChrisGray Painting is more complex then just "painting" components. You have a responsibility to maintain the paint chain, otherwise weird and wonderful things can go wrong. The `ImageObsever` provides some relivent information back to the API so the component can update itself should the `Image` change. It's "good practice" to do both

Comment: I understand that. I have been painting in swing and AWT for quite a while. Now, this Image is used as a buffer, I do not want it to be shown or redrawn onto the screen until it is complete. Updating the JPanel everytime the image is altered is a waste of processing power, there is no need for it. There are times when things that are "good practice" should be disregarded.

Comment: Sure, so long as you don't mind when it goes wrong. You should consider using a `BufferStrategy` instead and take complete control over the painting process, that's kind of what's it's designed for. Anyway, your problem is not a bug, it's mis-understanding or over sight, over the differences between what the two `drawImage` methods are doing, as well as a possible forgetfulness that the `JFrame` draws it's window decorations within the bounds of the frame, making it's contents smaller then it's actual window bounds. You could fix that by using `getPreferredSize` in the `GameScreen`

Comment: I know that, and I opted out of using a Canvas and bufferstrategy(I'd rather not list all my reasons why in a comment). I also could have called getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height); then called pack(). But for simplicity sake, and so I could write this up quickly, I opted out.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for helping me resolve this problem, I appreciate all your help :)

Comment: Just throwing things out there in case they stick ;)